# Channel Vigor While Paralyzed

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I cast channel vigor on my character the round before he was paralyzed with a spell, Hold Person.  Can I use my move action to change it from Torso to Mind?

I dont know if the hold person text, which specifically says you can do no actions, only mental, would mean you cannot use the move action to change from Torso to Mind.  Is the changing of the 'focus' actually requiring movement?

Answer (score 4):

### You can change your Channel Vigor

[Channel Vigor](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/channel-vigor/) states (flavor *italicized*):

> *You focus the energy of your mind, body, and spirit into a specific part of your being* [...] choose one of the following portions of your self as your focus target.

[Paralyzed](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/Conditions/#Paralyzed), as noted, allows that

> A paralyzed character is frozen in place and unable to move or act. A paralyzed character has effective Dexterity and Strength scores of 0 and is helpless, but can take purely mental **actions**.

Changing your Channel Vigor is a Move **Action** but the function of it is completely mental; you are changing the focus of a spell, making a different choice. The spell makes no mention of re-issuing the verbal nor somatic components of the spell, so we can only assume that it is a purely mental endeavor.